# Instantiate multiple objects with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am trying to use a $.each loop to instantiate multiple sliders, but for some reason i cannot call the methods/functions of the object.

This is how it is called now:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
  calculateHeight: true,
  loop: true,
  speed: 1000
  //moveStartThreshold: 200
})
$('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  mySwiper.swipePrev()
})
```

This is what i am trying to do

```
var swiper_objects = new Array();

$('.case-showcase .swiper-container').each(function(index){
  $(this).addClass( "sc-" + index );


  swiper_objects[index] = new Swiper('.swiper-container-' + index,{
    calculateHeight: true,
    loop: true,
    speed: 1000
  });

  $('.jq-case-showcase-' + index + ' .arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
    alert(swiper_objects[index]);
    e.preventDefault();
    swiper_objects[index].swipePrev();
  });

  //window["temp_" + data] = new Array();
  console.log('console: ' + index);

});
```

The error I get is: swiper_objects[index].swipePrev is not a function.

How can I fix this problem. If a for-loop would be better, that would be a viable option too.

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qv7hnycu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Having a thumbs up after your test I went back in and I saw some tiny typo's. This was just a part of the code, the errors were further down the line. Fixed them and all is fine now.

For those having the same sort of problem, the above code does work!

Thanks Arun P John.